# How to switch fragments by navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I know, there is a lot of similar questions, but I can't understand how to improve them.

My MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_blacktoolbar);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

}
}
```

My activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
        android:name="com.poliveira.apps.materialtests.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have also NavigationDrawerFragment.java and NavigationDrawerAdapter.java

So I want to change fragment by choosing item form my navigation drawer.
But don't know how to create these fragments with the same navigation drawer. 
Hope you understand what is on my mind, and will help me.

Comment: [Read this example](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

Comment: @TopCat Do you have any demo which I could you?

Comment: don't you have a list in your drawerlayout from where you "choose" list items and based on their position in list, you can create a new Fragment to show in your Framelayout (or your main view) when navigation drawer is closed